# JavaScript: Filtering dropdown list by value of other dropdown list

Tags: javascript, sql, function, variables, electron

I'm in need of some expert assistance.  I'm using Electron and have the three files shown below that, first, pulls data from a SQLite database (Data.js), then passes the data into a set of arrays and makes the data accessible in a dropdown list (Model.js and View.js).  The issue I have is I need the second dropdown list (that displays province names) to be filtered according to the country selected in the first dropdown.  As it currently stands, you get the full list of countries and the full list of provinces regardless of the country selected.

I have tried a few different options including using an onchange event listener (which hasn't worked correctly...most likely p.i.c.n.i.c.) along with trying to pass the element value backwards into the SQL query (which also hasn't worked as the value gets lost while traveling).  Can someone suggest what a proper method might be for doing this correctly?  Your help is much appreciated in advance!

Data.js:

```
function getCountries(done) {
var sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose();
var file = 'db/locations.sqlite3';
var db = new sqlite3.Database(file);
var larray = [];

db.all('SELECT * FROM Country', function(err, rows) {
    //  This code only gets called when the database returns with a response.
    rows.forEach(function(row) {
        larray.push({
            cname: row.CountryName,
            ccode: row.CountryCode
        });
    })
    return done(larray);
});
db.close();
}

function getProvinces(done) {
var sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose();
var file = 'db/locations.sqlite3';
var db = new sqlite3.Database(file);
var stmt = 'SELECT Country.CountryId, Country.CountryName, Province.ProvinceName, Province.ProvinceCode FROM Province INNER JOIN Country ON Province.CountryId = Country.CountryId'
var larray = [];

db.all(stmt, function(err, rows) {
        //  This code only gets called when the database returns with a response.
        rows.forEach(function(row) {
        larray.push({
            cname: row.CountryName,
            pname: row.ProvinceName,
            pcode: row.ProvinceCode
        });
    })
    return done(larray);
});
db.close();
```

Model.js:

```
function Countries(done) {
  //Pull location values from data
return getCountries(done);
}

function Provinces(done) {
//Pull location values from data
return getProvinces(done);
}
```

View.js:

```
function viewCountries() {

var viewCou =  Countries(function(results) {
    // Code only gets triggered when Countries() calls return done(...); 
    var container = document.getElementById('country-select');
    var fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();

    results.forEach(function(loc, index) { 
        var opt = document.createElement('option');
        opt.textContent = loc.cname;
        opt.value = loc.ccode;
        fragment.appendChild(opt);
    });
    container.appendChild(fragment);
})
}

function viewProvinces() {
var viewPro = Provinces(function(results) {
// Code only gets triggered when Provinces() calls return done(...); 
var container = document.getElementById('province-select');
var fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();

    results.forEach(function(loc, index) {
        var opt = document.createElement('option');
        opt.textContent = loc.pname;
        opt.value = loc.pcode;
        fragment.appendChild(opt);
        });
    container.appendChild(fragment);
});
}
```

HTML:

```
<p class="col-lg-2 col-md-4 col-sm-8 codes">COUNTRY</p>
<p id="country-value" class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-4 fieldval">No value entered</p>
<select required id="country-select" class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-8 formselect">
<option selected> ----Select---- </option>
</select>          
<label class="col-lg-4 col-md-3 col-sm-8 descr">Country code of sample</label>
<p class="col-lg-2 col-md-4 col-sm-8 codes">PROVINCE</p>
<p id="province-value" class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-4 fieldval">No value entered</p>
<select required id="province-select" class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-8 formselect">
<option selected> ----Select---- </option>                
</select>    
<label class="col-lg-4 col-md-3 col-sm-8 descr">Provence code of sample</label>
```

Comment: Have you already tried only filling the second dropdown after the first is selected?

Comment: Yes.  The first dropdown is run onload of the page, the second is run onchange.  It didn't seem to work, but again it could have been how it was implemented.  Not necessarily that the idea was bad.

Comment: Writing you answer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are on the right way.

1. First of all, you should continue using `onchange` event. It will listen when you change a country. When this happen, it means it's time to change the province `select`.  Also, always when you change the country, you should reset the province `select` to avoid trash from previous usage.

> `<select id="country-select" onchange="onCountryChanged()"></select>`
>
> ```
> function onCountryChanged() {
>     resetProvincesSelect();
>     viewProvinces($("#country-select").val());
> }
>
> function resetProvincesSelect() {
>     var container = document.getElementById('province-select');
>     $(container).empty();
> }
> ```

2. You must change your `viewProvinces` function to accept one parameter, the country code, or `ccode`. Also, you need to `.filter()` the `results` array, getting only the provinces that belongs to that country (`ccode`).

> ```
> function viewProvinces(ccode) {
>     var viewPro = Provinces(function(results) {
>         // Code only gets triggered when Provinces() calls return done(...); 
>         var container = document.getElementById('province-select');
>         var fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
>         results.filter(function(el) {
>             return el.ccode === ccode;
>         }).forEach(function(loc, index) {
>             var opt = document.createElement('option');
>             opt.textContent = loc.pname;
>             opt.value = loc.pcode;
>             fragment.appendChild(opt);
>         });
>         container.appendChild(fragment);
>     });
> }
> ```

3. You need to include `ccode` to `getProvinces()`

> ```
> {
>     ccode: row.CountryCode,
>     cname: row.CountryName,
>     pname: row.ProvinceName,
>     pcode: row.ProvinceCode
> }
> ```

4. You have not provided where you're calling the main function. So, generically it will be in this way

> `viewCountries();`

Optionally you can preload all provinces along side with the countries. So when you select the country, you will not need to fetch the provinces. It is a specific designing choice. You can also make `Provinces` or `getProvinces` receive `ccode`, abstracting this step from the view.

I hope it helps you.

Comment: You can use `cname` instead of `ccode`. But when you look into the perfomance, you will prefer compairing a short than a large string. You could also provide an `integer`. It will improve the perfomance of your code!

Comment: Thank you, Richard!  This is perfect and even better...works!  I was playing with it more today before your post and I was starting down the road which you just presented, but it still wasn't right nor do I think I would have gotten there.  But, thank you.  You're help is very much appreciated!